# Running a different code for each Handler/ Timer/ Thread execution

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I know how to user a Handler or a Timer/ Thread/ etc. You call the handler, and start/ stop it where it is needed in the code. Typically, a handler will run a certain code over and over again until it is stopped. I am wondering if there is a way to run a different code for each execution. One way I thought of would be to do as follows.

```
Handler h = new Handler();
int delay = 1000; //milliseconds
int handlerCount = 0;

h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        //update handler count
        handlerCount = handlerCount + 1;
        if (handlerCount ==1 ) {
            //run code 1  
        } 
        if (handlerCount ==2) {
            //run code 2
        } // etc.
        h.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```

Or if you need to do a different code every other time, you would do

```
if (handlerCount%2 == 0) {
    //Do first function
} else {// do second function}
```

Is this the best way to do it? It doesn't seem very clean but it works fine, so I am wondering if there are better ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this

```
Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case case1:
                //ops for case1
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Then to send message to `Handler` use the below code

```
handler.obtainMessage(what, arg1, arg2, dataobj)
//what - integer to identify this message
//arg1 - optional integer argument1
//arg1 - optional integer argument2
//dataobject - optional data object to be passed
```

Comment: Is that only for messages? Or can you put general code, such as textView.setText("text");?

Comment: yes you can add general code too. because that is handler for main thread